# How to Allow Mapping of drive to internet location

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-registry

1.I wish to map a drive letter(let's say J:) to an internet share site(lets say https://site.sharesite.com), which is the sharesite used by head office. We have a program which transfers files across from local C drives to internet share.

2.This was **working very reliably for months** until the weekend, where possibly Policy changes, patches etc take place, and now we cannot map to internet location such as this (still able to map to a network drive). We reliably used command line bat file: net use J: https:\\site.sharesite.com\webdav\xxx /USER:"My UserName" MyPassword

**Edit**: Now get this error 1244

[image]

3.IS are happy to allow as it's Head Office site, but they do not know how or why the ability was lost.

4.I would assume there is some registry setting which will allow the ability to map to the internet location

I am looking at : `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer` `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`

But I do not know what else to do. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using forward-slashes (`/`) instead of back-slashes (``\``)? (also there should be two forward-slashes after the colon, i.e. `https://`)

Comment: @3D1T0R , that missing slash is just Super User formatting. I cannot stress enough that this has worked reliably for months. I guess i could try the forward slashes, but as I say, this has worked for months...

Comment: Have you tried mapping this drive letter with the GUI? If it doesn't work either, then its error message may be informative. To do so: open Computer, go to the ribbon, and under the "Computer" section, click "Map Network Drive". See [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64L5I.png) for reference. Also, *definitely* use forward-slashes in the URL.

Comment: Just established that the bat script in the OP still works for machines in one domain, but those in the other domain do not. There is something about the client-side for those machines that the machines/proxies have changed.

Comment: the screenshot you posted says its an authentication issue.  have the admins look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Oh We found the issue to be that the sharesite has mandated TLS 1.2

So updating registry keys to use that protocol solved the issue.

Thanks for your time.